# AccessViolationException in PInvoke function call

Tags: c#, memory, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I'm trying to write a wrapper for C library but I'm really struggling with this error.

I tried many approaches, here is one of them:

```
    [DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
    private static extern uint GetData(IntPtr handle,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray), In()] int[] buffer,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint size);
```

Here is function *GetData* from the library documentation:

```
LONG GetData( 
  IN HANDLE Handle,
  OUT PULONG Buffer, 
  IN ULONG Size
);
```

Function returns continuous data (about 16KB/s) in buffer which size is given in bytes. *Buffer* is *int[16384]*. My code looks like this:

```
public static uint GetLibData(IntPtr handle, int[] buffer, uint size)
    {
        size *= 4;            
        uint sizeRead = GetData(handle, buffer, size);

        sizeRead /= 4;

        return sizeRead;
    }
```

Problematic argument is *buffer*, I tried manage it previously in other ways, such as *IntPtr bufferPtr* and then allocating memory by *Marshal.AllocHGlobal* but I was getting the same error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

How to correctly invoke this function?

Comment: You didn't specify the CallingConvention, good odds it is Cdecl.

Comment: @HansPassant: thanks. I've just tried all possible coventions but none of them changed this error ("_Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt._")

Comment: You'll need to start debugging the C code to narrow down why it crashed.  If you don't have it then ask for help from the owner.

Comment: Attach native debugger to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate p/invoke declaration is

```
[DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME)]
private static extern uint GetData(
    IntPtr handle,
    [Out] uint[] buffer,
    uint size
);
```

It is your responsibility to allocate the buffer before you call the function:

```
uint[] buffer = new uint[16384];
uint bufferSize = buffer.Length*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint));
uint sizeRead = GetData(handle, buffer, bufferSize);
uint lenRead = sizeRead/Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint));
```

The only thing that's not 100% clear is the calling convention. I'd guess that this library uses `cdecl` which would mean your `DllImport` should be

```
[DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following PInvoke:

```
[DllImport(DRIVER_FILENAME)]
private static extern Int32 GetData
(
    [In] IntPtr handle,
    [Out] out IntPtr buffer,
    [In] UInt32 size
);
```

Comment: The second parameter is `PULONG`. That's a point to `uint` passed by value. So, one fewer levels of indirection than in your answer.